# Maximum allowed digits after decimal for double

Tags: double, digits

> Hi,
>
> I want to know how many number of digits are allowed after decimal
>   point for primitive double datatype in java, without actually getting
>   rounded off.

Comment: It's not a matter of digits after the decimal point but of "significant digits" in general. It'll be at least 10.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number; read up on [floating point representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) for more information.

Use the [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class for fixed-scale arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Taken literally, the number is 0. Most decimal fractions with at least one digit after the decimal point get rounded on conversion to double. For example, the decimal fraction `0.1` is rounded to `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` on conversion to double.

The problem is that double is a binary floating point system, and most decimal fractions can no more be exactly represented in than 1/3 can be exactly represented as a decimal fraction with a finite number of significant digits.

As already recommended, if truly exact representation of decimal fractions is important, use `BigDecimal`.

The primitive double has, for normal numbers, 53 significant bits, about 15.9 decimal digits. If very, very close is good enough, you can use double.